# Linking one ending point to another

Tags: uml, plantuml

Is there a way to create multiple separate ending points in plantuml and/or to link the one ending point from inside the composite state, directly to the one of the outer ending state? It's more of visual things, than anything but i wonder if you can do that. Look at pictures

[image: Problem 1]

[image: Problem 2]

Comment: Welcome please supply the details. Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Especially the last part (example / code).

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting something wrong.  The top left is how it needs to be. The right one is just wrong. A `FlowFinal` has no token to pass. It just ends the surrounding environment (*smthing*). Right then *smthing* will pass a token to your outer `FlowFinal`.

No idea what you intend with the lower picture.

Comment: maybe OP wants something alike http://forum.plantuml.net/8029/how-show-start-element-outside-partitions-activity-diagrams with my answer on the subsequent question, but without code we don't know.